# Random alphanumeric pin?

Tags: php

I'm working on creating a random 5 character pin for a script. I was wondering if anyone else had a better one?

```
$pin = '';
while($i != 5){
    $string = '23456789abcdefghjkmnprstvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ'; 
    $pos = rand(0,(strlen($string)-1));
    $pin = $pin . $string[$pos];
    $i++;
}

echo $pin;
```

Comment: I want my pin to be HELL or FACK, i.e., you might want to remove all vowels.

Comment: you are omitting 1, l, 0, and O on purpose for readability right?

Comment: along the same lines, arent a lot of lowercase/capital letters confusable as well?  like `v` and `V` ??

Comment: use mt_rand() instead of rand(),  rand() is known not to be so random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just marginally different/shorter.  No reason to declare the valid characters every time, and for loop is often considered preferable to while.

```
$pinlength = 5;
$charSet = '23456789abcdefghjkmnprstvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ'; 
$pin = '';
for($a = 0; $a < $pinlength; $a++) $pin .= $charSet[rand(0, strlen($charSet))];

echo $pin;
```

Or, just for the hell of it:

```
$makeCharacterSelect = 
         function ($charSet) {return function use ($charSet) 
                                     {return $charSet[rand(0, strlen($charSet))];};
$pinlength = 5; $c = $makeCharacterSelect('23456789abcdefghjkmnprstvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ');

$pin = '';
for($a = 0; $a < $pinlength; $a++) $pin .= $c();
```

Comment: I think you mean `$pin .= ` and `rand` not `$rand`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pin = substr(uniqid(), 0, 5); // Mind you, this doesn't contain
                               // upper-case letters
```

Comment: this will include the undesired characters.  its also far from random, though that probably isnt a big deal